# How to get Lat and Long from google in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get `lat and long` from google using react native . I am new to React native and did not find any resource to resolve my issue . Could someone please help me??

Thanks

Comment: lat/long of what exactly? Question is far too vague for a reasonable answer

Answer (score 0):

Have to add to your proyect react-native-geolocation-service, here is the link
https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition is the method i use to get location.